# Inserting to 1:m relation java spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I have 1:m relation. I post data about "1" and also about "m" relation in one post. What i am trying to achieve is to insert data ( m ) into "1" , then persist 1 into database which should create info in database about 1 and about m.

The "1" Enitity:

```
 private List<OptionEntity> options;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "survey", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    public List<OptionEntity> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<OptionEntity> options) {
        this.options= options;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "survey_id", nullable = false)
    public int getSurveyId() {
        return surveyId;
    }

    public void setSurveyId(int surveyId) {
        this.surveyId = surveyId;
    }
```

the "m" entitites

private SurveyEntity survey;

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="survey_id")
public SurveyEntity getSurvey() {
    return survey;
}

public void setSurvey(SurveyEntity survey ) {
    this.survey = survey;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "option_id", nullable = false)
public int getOptionId() {
    return optionId;
}

public void setOptionId(int optionId) {
    this.optionId = optionId;
}
```

However when i do

```
List<OptionEntity> ops = new ArrayList<>();
for( String option : options ){
    OptionEntity tmp_option = new OptionEntity();
    tmp_option.setText( option );
    ops.add(tmp_option);
}
survey.setOptions(ops);
surveyDAO.add(survey);
```

when add is

```
public void add ( SurveyEntity s )
{
  em.persist( s );
}
```

Creates only record for "1" entity in database. The records for all "m" entities are not inserted in the databases.

I thought whats important here is identity set to AUTO for m entities so database can create their id ( it has autoincrement ).

Seems i am wrong in this one.

What is the correct way to insert into 1:m  relation at once?

Thanks for help

Comment: You have configured cascading for the merge operation only. Not for persist. So the options are not persisted when you persist the survey. You also forgot to set the survey of the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things:

**1)** Set the relationship on both sides, so in the loop add the Survey entity to each of the Option entities:

```
       for( String option : options ){
           OptionEntity tmp_option = new OptionEntity();
           tmp_option.setText( option );
           ops.add(tmp_option);
           tmp_option.setSurvey(survey);
       }
```

**2)** Either use `em.merge()` instead of `em.persist()` or add this cascade option:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "survey", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
public List<OptionEntity> getOptions() {
    return options;
}
```

Comment: When i use merge or those cascades it throws 
SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Comment: during query invocation or during container startup?

Comment: during the query invocation

Comment: I have found that names of my attributes are reserved words for mysql , i just escaped names and it works , thanks